# Azure Function in PowerShell to untar file

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to convert some a number of files compressed into a .tar.gz archive into a single file. To do so I need to first untar the file.

I have a copy of 7z.exe loaded into the directory, and calling the command locally works

```
.\7z.exe x *.tar.gz
```

I've uploaded the exe into the wwwroot/poshUntar directory alongside the run.ps1 file that gets executed, and using the online editor I can execute the powershell script. I would of course expect my function to fail generally since I'm not providing the variable values but I would not expect it to error about finding the 7z.exe file

```
.\7z.exe : The term '.\7z.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\home\site\wwwroot\poshUntar\run.ps1:10 char:1
+ .\7z.exe x *.tar -o logs
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\7z.exe:String) [], CommandNot 
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**What is the correct way to invoke an executable inside a PowerShell Azure Function?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you also need to upload 7z.dll into the wwwroot directory.

Could you try using the following code-segment in your script?

```
Set-Location D:\home\site\wwwroot\poshUntar
.\7z.exe x *.tar.gz 
.\7z.exe x *.tar -ologs
```

Comment: FYI: for tools like 7z that you may want to reuse across multiple functions, you can put them in the `D:\home\site\tools` folder. The runtime automatically adds that to the PATH.